# How to make only one expected value in Pydantic dataclass

Tags: python, automated-tests, pydantic

I'm trying to make one or more expected values non-literal. But I get error TypeError: non-default argument 'breakdownAccount' follows default argument.

This example raised error:

```
@dataclass
class DataInclude:
    currencyAccount: Literal["CNY счет", "AMD счет", "RUB счет", "USD счет", "EUR счет", "GBP счет", "CHF счет"]
    open: bool = True
    accountType: Literal["Текущий счет"]
    currencyCode: Literal[810, 826, 756, 978, 840, 51, 156]
    currency: Literal['CNY', 'AMD', 'RUB', 'USD', 'EUR', 'GBP', 'CHF']
```

This example working:

```
@dataclass
class DataInclude:
    currencyAccount: Literal["CNY счет", "AMD счет", "RUB счет", "USD счет", "EUR счет", "GBP счет", "CHF счет"]
    open: bool
    accountType: Literal["Текущий счет"]
    currencyCode: Literal[810, 826, 756, 978, 840, 51, 156]
    currency: Literal['CNY', 'AMD', 'RUB', 'USD', 'EUR', 'GBP', 'CHF']
```

How can I put in expected values if they are static?

I use all this for API autotests

I have searched everywhere for this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fields without default values cannot appear after fields with default values.
Declare the `open` field as the last one.

```py
from typing import Literal
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class DataInclude:
    currencyAccount: Literal[
        "CNY счет",
        "AMD счет",
        "RUB счет",
        "USD счет",
        "EUR счет",
        "GBP счет",
        "CHF счет",
    ]
    accountType: Literal["Текущий счет"]
    currencyCode: Literal[810, 826, 756, 978, 840, 51, 156]
    currency: Literal["CNY", "AMD", "RUB", "USD", "EUR", "GBP", "CHF"]
    open: bool = True
```